# Views block show content older than current node created date

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Pretty much as per the question, how would I go about creating a view that only showed content older than the current node's created date?

I've created the argument using 'Content: created date' but struggling to pass this over to the filter criteria.

To be honest, I'm not even sure this is the correct way to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working with a Views PHP field:

```
<?php
global $base_path;

if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2)) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $a1 = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');
  $a2 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-2 months",strtotime($a1)));  
  $a3 = format_date($row->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');

  $b1 = new DateTime($a1);
  $b2 = new DateTime($a2);
  $b3 = new DateTime($a3);

  if ($b3 >= $b2 && $b3 <= $b1) {
    print '<h2><a href="'. $base_path . 'node/' . $row->nid . '">' . $row->title . '</a></h2>' . $data->field_body[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
    //dsm($data);
  }
}
?>
```